# Is it possible to install chef-solo without root privilege

Tags: installation, chef-infra, centos5, chef-solo

We have been facing with a lot of issues with Linux team about installing stuff on a VM. We are not given any root access and as far as I understand chef is impossible to install without root privilege at all. Am I correct? If I'm wrong is there anyway I can install chef-solo on Centos 5.x without root access? I have run the command from chef website

`curl -L https://www.opscode.com/chef/install.sh | bash`

And I got permission denied error which of course I don't have root access. Is there anyway to workaround this issue?

Comment: Chef is severely limited if it's not running as root. For example packages cannot be installed (not just chef :-)). I'd recommend attempting to get chef server and client installed. That way still no root access, but changes applied as cookbooks which can be reviewed.

Comment: `chef-solo` running as an unprivileged user has one interesting use case that I've found so far - management of your dotfiles.  For example emacs, bash etc is easy to configure on a new host by pulling down a cookbook and running it with `chef-solo`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure - you can install Chef as a gem as non-root if you're running rvm or a similar userspace gem manager.

```
$ gem install chef
Fetching: chef-11.6.0.gem (100%)
Successfully installed chef-11.6.0
1 gem installed

$ which chef-solo
/Users/tpot/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/bin/chef-solo
```